# fabric.js moving an object underneath another object

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I have two layers(0,1). 0 being the bottom image on a canvas, and 1 the top. Layer 0 is a human body template, layer 1 are some eyes. I want to be able to move the bottom most layer(the body layer), without moving the top layer or covering up the top layer. Basically, have the eyes sit on the body and are visible, but able to move the body image around. Ive been able to achieve most of this with:

```
canvas.item(0).selectable = true;
canvas.item(0).evented = true;
canvas.item(1).selectable = false;
canvas.item(1).evented = false;
```

However, when i then start to drag layer 0 around(the human body layer), it brings that layer to the top and covers the eyes, even though when I print the array of objects, it still says the body layer is index 0. What am i missing? is this even possible? Moving a lower layer underneath higher visible layers?

This is how I'm adding the layers originally:

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgString, function(oImg) {

        oImg.scale(0.4);
        canvas.centerObject(oImg);
        canvas.add(oImg);

        canvas.renderAll();


    });
```

Comment: ahhh it was .evented that i missed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding

```
preserveObjectStacking: true
```

to canvas initializer fixed this.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainCanvas',{
        preserveObjectStacking: true
    });
```

Comment: I did this, but now I'm having some trouble selecting elements over another. For example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/filiperoberto/zLz6cy2L/4/  select the bigger rect and try to select the text after that